# Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Tenho um banco MySql com diversas stored procedures, como liberar apenas uma para um determinado usuário?

I have a database MySql with several stored procedures, how to release only one for a specific user?

Estou utilizando PHPMyAdmin. Em privilégios do usuário, se eu marcar a opção EXECUTE , ele libera o acesso para todas as procedures do BD.  Preciso liberar apenas uma procedure para um determinado usuário.  Não quero que ele veja as demais procedures.

O PHPMyAdmin executa o seguinte comando quando marco a opção EXECUTE :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `db\_mdm`.* TO 'mdm_user'@'%';
```

Já tentei trocar o * pelo nome da Procedure, porém sem sucesso.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `db\_mdm`.`minha_procedure` TO 'mdm_user'@'%';
```

Com tabelas e views eu consigo restringir o que esse usuário pode ver ou fazer. Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa com stored procedures.

Comment: Consagrado, precisamos de mais detalhes, edita a pergunta e insere trechos do que já tentou fazer!

Comment: Editado Jonathan! Me ajuda aeh...rsrs